# remove git head from files <<<<<<head

Tags: git

I have a bit of unique situation.  A folder containing a large library has been committed into our repo with get headers still in it (ex: `<<<<<<<Head`).  However these are not recognized by git, nor are they listed as conflicts.  As far as git is concerned all is well.  However, the presence of these headers makes the library impossible to run.  I know everyone's first impulse is to say, "this can't happen, that's the whole point of git."  Well it has happened, and it seems like I need to manually clear these headers out of this library.

Here is `git status` after `git reset --hard` and `git commit`

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

here's trying to run a file in the library:

```
pip freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\jmarshall\source\repos\MediaDesignGroup\ETLApp_Dev\ETLApp\ETLAppEnv_3_7\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>   
  File "c:\users\jmarshall\source\repos\mediadesigngroup\etlapp_dev\etlapp\etlappenv_3_7\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 60
    <<<<<<< HEAD
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: I'm afraid that the issue here is not just that you have merge markers left behind.  A potentially even bigger problem is that the code itself has not been properly merged.  I wouldn't have much confidence at all in these source files.  You should go back to before the point in your history when this happened, and try to reconcile from there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  wow, sure feels like 2020 doesn't it.  Any idea how this sort of thing may have occurred in the first place?

Comment: “I know everyone's first impulse is to say, "this can't happen, that's the whole point of git."” No, no one thinks that. It is very easy to make this happen: in a conflict, declare the conflict resolved without having edited the workspace version of the file. Git didn’t make any mistake here; humans did.

Comment: In addition to Matt's comment, we're not saying that _you_ did this, you probably wouldn't, but maybe someone else on the team did.  One sanity check which I almost _always_ do before pushing anything to a Git repo is to do a full local build.  This ensures that anything I push out is at least guaranteed to _build_.  The files you have here won't even build, and that's just sloppy work on someone else's part, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah I'm just batting clean up here.  Never seen this before.  If the answer its simply not recoverable, could you post an answer to that affect?  Its worth having around the next time someone googles this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a bit of unique situation

It’s not particularly unique actually.

> I know everyone's first impulse is to say, "this can't happen, that's the whole point of git."

No, it's very easy to make this happen. I'll demonstrate!

I'll start a repo:

```
$ echo a > a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -ma
$ git branch b
$ echo c > a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -mc
```

Now I'll create a conflict and merge it:

```
$ git switch b
$ echo b > a.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -mb
$ git switch master
$ git merge b
```

Now Git reports the conflict:

```
Auto-merging a.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in a.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Okay, ready? I'll make the problem happen. Here we go:

```
$ git add a.txt
$ git commit -moops
```

That's all it takes! Do you see what I did? I didn't fix the conflict markup in *a.txt*, but I told Git that I had fixed it, and I committed. Now this version of *a.txt* has been commited!

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
c
=======
b
>>>>>>> b
```

So you see it's actually quite trivial to make this mistake. Git has no idea what's in the merge conflict file; fixing it and saying so, honestly, is the responsibility of *humans.*

Now, in the simple example I just gave, fixing the issue at this point is easy; the file still has the original merge conflict markers, so do what you should have done before: edit the file to fix the conflict (pick c or b, or whatever), removing the markers, and add, and commit!

But whether the OP's situation will admit of such a simple solution is doubtful at this point.

Comment: This is a good explanation so I don't want to downvote it, but it doesn't really give a *solution*.

Comment: The solution in the example I gave would be to resolve the conflict and commit again. But I’ve no idea whether the OP can do that at this point. I’ll add that info.

Comment: @xdhmoore - tim advised in the question comments that even if I did clean the headers out of the files, I might not be able to trust the content of the files. It seems that I'm SOL is the solution here.

Comment: @JamieMarshall They are not "headers". They just show you the conflict(s). You would have had to resolve them in any case. The question is, can you do that now? I am not so dubious about this; after all, this situation can't have been in force very long, because if it had been, you would have noticed before.

Comment: How do you go back to just before the change was made and start from there?

Comment: Reset hard to just before the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

I once faced the same problem, and it seems that git does recognize it as a problem. But here there is a simple solution.

- first copy all data in the file excluding the line causing conflict
- Then try deleting the file that has the issue and recreates the file again

> $ git rm file_with_issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).